# Change WPF window's label content from child user control

Tags: c#, wpf

I have wpf window named 'GetStarted' with grid which is perent of user control 'Step1'

```
Step1 s1 = new Step1();
mainGrid.Children.Add(s1);
```

on `step1` is button with this code

```
 private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
            etStarted gt = new GetStarted();
            gt.image0.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            gt.lblSteps.Content= "Step 2 of 5";
 }
```

but when I press `btnNext` nothing happens.

Comment: Where do you hook up the button click event? Can you post the XAML for Step1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is creating a new Window instance. If you want to get the Window containing the UC you can call Window.GetWindow and then cast to your specific Window type:

```
    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var gt = Window.GetWindow(this) as GetStarted;
        if (gt != null)
        {
            gt.image0.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            gt.lblSteps.Content = "Step 2 of 5";
        }
    }
```